# PHP date format and strtotime

Tags: php

I would like to get a `Y-m-d` formatted date from a string like "28 January 1959".

I tried `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateString))`, but it returns 1970-01-01.

The weird thing is that, if I debug the above code with "28 January 1959" constant, it works, but if I replace the string with the variable which stores the same value, it returns 1970-01-01.

Any idea?

Comment: Your code is working fine!!.

Comment: where do u get your string date?

Comment: from an external web api (http://www.myapifilms.com)

Comment: would u post the date format you get from this api

Comment: the sample I wrote in my question ("28 January 1959") is from the API.

Comment: Since your code is workin fine online and on my machine it's probably your system has the issue or your server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is remove special characters from the date string:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $dateString)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the reason why this happens is because your system can't handle negative time stamps. The unix timestamp which is created by `strtotime` has 1970-01-01 00:00:00 as zero-point. Any date before that is a negative number, any date after is a positive number. I think for some reason your system can't interpret a negative number for a timestamp.

I'm not sure if it helps but the PHP website has [a few remarks on this issue](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes).

I'm curious what this would output: `date('Y-m-d', -1)`, which should be *1969-12-31*.

Comment: date('Y-m-d', -1) output 1969-12-31

Comment: And `strtotime('28 January 1959')` outputs '-344822400'?

Comment: And `date('Y-m-d', -344822400)` works too? And `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('28 January 1969'))` too?

Are there any special characters you can't see? This is about the last solution I can think of because it works fine everywhere.

Comment: Yes, there were special characters in the date string.That was the problem (as you see above). Thanks for help.